# Scala: a strange bahaviour of seqAsJavaList

Tags: scala

Given the following code:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._

def j(x: java.util.List[java.lang.Integer]): Unit = 
    // the function body here can be any valid code
    println (x)

val a = List(1)
```

I get a type mismatch error when I call this:

```
j (seqAsJavaList(a))
```

Here is the error from REPL

```
 <console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: Seq[Integer]
          f (seqAsJavaList(a))
                           ^
```

However, I can call this with no error:

```
 j(seqAsJavaList(List(1)))
```

I'm using 2.11.2.

Can someone explain to me why seqAsJavaList behaves differently? Thanks.

---

Adding more context/clarification to my original question:

What I meant to ask was "why does `seqAsJavaList` behave differently when operating on a predefined variable `a` than on an in-place value `List(1)` when they are of the same type?" Furthermore `seqAsJavaList(a)` and `seqAsJavaList (List(1))` return exactly the same signature `java.util.List[Int]`. Using the substitution model, one would expect both `j (seqAsJavaList(a))` and `j (seqAsJavaList (List(1)) )` to succeed. And yet, only the latter works. When both `seqAsJavaList(a)` and `seqAsJavaList (List(1))` are `java.util.List[Int]`, why does one usage handle `Int` well and the other doesn't?

---

Another note:

I just tried `collection.JavaConverters` and the result is not ideal but at least consistent:

```
// The definitions of j & a are the same as above. I repeat them here to save some page scrolling.
// BTW, instead of f, I use j to indicate it is supposed to be a Java static method.
// I mock it in Scala so that this can be easily run in REPL.
def j ( ls: java.util.List [java.lang.Integer] ): Unit = println (ls)
val a = List( 1 )
// new code here
import collection.JavaConverters._
// Both require the explicit casting to work
j ( a.map (i => i: java.lang.Integer).asJava )
j ( List(1).map (i => i: java.lang.Integer).asJava )

// These fail with the same error.
j( a.asJava )
j( List(1).asJava )
// <console>:12: error: type mismatch;
// found   : java.util.List[Int]
// required: java.util.List[Integer]
//          j ( List(1).asJava )
//                      ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is not with `List` but with its type `Int`. For example this works:

```
scala> j ( seqAsJavaList (a.map(x => x:Integer)) )
[1]
```

`j` expects argument type as `java.util.List [java.lang.Integer]`. But the return type of `seqAsJavaList` in your case is `java.util.List [Int]`.

The above example works because now seqAsJavaList will take `List [java.lang.Integer]` and return `java.util.List[java.lang.Integer]`. Hence it works.

Or you could:

```
scala> implicit def toJavaIntegerList(ls:List[Int]):java.util.List[Integer] = seqAsJavaList(ls.map(x => x:Integer))

scala> j(List(1,2,3))
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

To explain why this works:

```
j (seqAsJavaList(List(1)))
```

This is equivalent to:

```
scala> val temp:List[Integer] = List(1)
temp: List[Integer] = List(1)

scala> j (seqAsJavaList(temp))
[1]
```

Or better: `j (seqAsJavaList(List(1:Integer)))`

Type-inference is in work here. There is an implicit function

```
implicit def int2Integer(x:Int):java.lang.Integer
```

defined in [Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$). When you do `j(seqAsJavaList(List(1)))`, type inference predicts that this can succeed legitimately by using implicit function which converts `Int => java.lang.Integer`. It sees that if this implicit is used with all elements of `List`, then call will succeed legitimately. So `List(1)` is actually constructed as `List[Integer]` rather than `List[Int]`

This is confirmed by checking

```
object Temp extends App{
        import collection.JavaConversions._

        def j(x: java.util.List[java.lang.Integer]): Unit =  println (x)
        j(seqAsJavaList(List(1)))
}

jatinpuri@jatin:~/Desktop$ scalac -Xprint:typer Temp.scala 
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // Temp.scala
package <empty> {
  object Temp extends AnyRef with App {
    def <init>(): Temp.type = {
      Temp.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._;
    def j(x: java.util.List[Integer]): Unit = scala.this.Predef.println(x);
    Temp.this.j(scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList[Integer](immutable.this.List.apply[Integer](scala.this.Predef.int2Integer(1))))
  }
}
```

Notice `(immutable.this.List.apply[Integer](scala.this.Predef.int2Integer(1)))`. So `List(1)` is actually constructed as `List[Integer]` and not `List[Int]`

This doesn't work in original case because in doing `val a = List(1)`, `a` is set as `List[Int]`. And the only way to change it to `List[Integer]` is map all contents to Integer (as there is no implicit available in scala lib that converts `List[Int] => List[Integer]`)

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking the time. It's still a bit fuzzy to me though. Let me explain.

I already figured out I had to do either `seqAsJavaList (a.map (x => x: java.lang.Integer))` (as you mentioned) or `seqAsJavaList (a).asInstanceOf [java.util.List [java.lang.Integer]]` to get the correct type.

I understand and agree with what you said: seqAsJavaList returns a java.util.List [Int] while my function f expects a java.util.List [java.lang.Integer].

Perhaps I should have been more explicit when I asked "why seqAsJavaList behaves differently". (To be continued in my next comment)

Comment: What I meant to ask was "why does seqAsJavaList behave differently when operating on a predefined variable `a` than on an in-place value `List(1)` when they are of the same type?" Furthermore `seqAsJavaList(a)` and `seqAsJavaList (List(1))` return exactly the same signature `java.util.List[Int]`.

Using the substitution model, one would expect both `j (seqAsJavaList(a))` and `j (seqAsJavaList (List(1)) )` to succeed. And yet, only the latter works.

When both `seqAsJavaList(a)` and `seqAsJavaList (List(1))` are `java.util.List[Int]`, why does one usage handles `Int` well and the other doesn't?

Comment: Excellent follow-up with evidence in full display. AST certainly doesn't lie. Thank you very much. I accept this as the answer.